# docker-compose healthcheck issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, health-check

I'm currently working on a microservice project using docker-compose. So I was adding health checks to my containers. But except mysql every thing else stays unhealthy but I don't know why.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 52.78.52.254
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dnjscksdn98@
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=explanet_dev
      - MYSQL_USER=alex
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dnjscksdn98@
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "mysql", "-u$$MYSQL_USER", "-p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  api-gateway:
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    build:
      context: ./api-gateway
      args:
        ENVIRONMENT: dev
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://api-gateway/health-check" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  chatting-service:
    container_name: chatting-service
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    build:
      context: ./chatting-service
      args:
        ENVIRONMENT: dev
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://chatting-service:8080/health-check" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - kafka
      - api-gateway
```

And if I type `docker inspect ${any container name}` it shows like this in the `State`.

```
"Health": {
                "Status": "unhealthy",
                "FailingStreak": 12,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-12-01T04:47:28.090046668Z",
                        "End": "2020-12-01T04:47:28.158193366Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-12-01T04:47:58.162656864Z",
                        "End": "2020-12-01T04:47:58.233280387Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-12-01T04:48:28.238446336Z",
                        "End": "2020-12-01T04:48:28.325520772Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-12-01T04:48:58.330407168Z",
                        "End": "2020-12-01T04:48:58.398503364Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2020-12-01T04:49:28.403163576Z",
                        "End": "2020-12-01T04:49:28.477627297Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

My java Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
COPY build/libs/base-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar base-service.jar
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${ENVIRONMENT}
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "base-service.jar"]
```

I'm currently running on Ubuntu 20.04 server. Is there any solutions?

Comment: Are you sure your healthcheck links are working fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello the error message is pretty clear, you can't run curl for health check because it's not included in base image you use, you need to install it.
Exemple for [alpine images](https://www.shellhacks.com/alpine-install-curl/)

Comment: This was it..!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Besides having to install `curl` on the Alpine base image with `apk add curl`,so that you use `curl` to run the test, you might also want to upgrade the `depends_on` configuration using `condition: service_healthy`.

```
depends_on:
  api-gateway:
    condition: service_healthy
```

Because, as far as I know, `depends_on` only check if the service has *started* and does not wait for *healthy* status unless the condition was explicitly defined.